# how can i drawContours answer sheet from left to right

Tags: python, opencv, contour, omr

*help*
how can i do about this code 
i want to answer check from answer sheet top-bottom then left-right
but this code do left-right and top-bottom

```
for (q, i) in enumerate(np.arange(0, len(questionCnts), 5)):
    # sort the contours for the current question from
    # left to right, then initialize the index of the
    # bubbled answer
    cnts = contours.sort_contours(questionCnts[i:i + 5])[0]
    bubbled = None  


    # loop over the sorted contours
    for (j, c) in enumerate(cnts):
        # construct a mask that reveals only the current
        # "bubble" for the question
        mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 255, -1)

        # apply the mask to the thresholded image, then
        # count the number of non-zero pixels in the
        # bubble area
        mask = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, thresh, mask=mask)
        total = cv2.countNonZero(mask)

        # if the current total has a larger number of total
        # non-zero pixels, then we are examining the currently
        # bubbled-in answer
        if bubbled is None or total > bubbled[0]:
            bubbled = (total, j)

    # initialize the contour color and the index of the
    # *correct* answer
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    k = ANSWER_KEY[q]

    # check to see if the bubbled answer is correct
    if k == bubbled[1]:
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        correct += 1

    # draw the outline of the correct answer on the test
    cv2.drawContours(paper, [cnts[k]], -1, color, -1)
```

[img 1 answerSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYyxM.png)
[img 2 answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ88q.jpg)
you will see the answer sheet in **img1** but the real answer is **img2** in **img2** answer 1 is A
answer 2 is 2 but now in the **img1** answer 11 is 2 
how can i do

Answer (score 0):

Before you start iterating over all the contours, sort all of them based on y co-ordinate.
Then start iterating in batches of 10(each row) and sort each batch based on x co-ordinate.
This way you will get every contour in the right sequence.